# libusb-0.1.so.4 shared lib error in ubuntu 64 bit system

Tags: 64-bit, shared-library

I am trying to install ZTE MF191 driver in ubuntu 12.04 64 bit machine. I am not sure is it support 64 bit or not. But it works fine in 32bit system. These driver package has a executable file named **zr** When i try to run this it throws an error

```
libusb-0.1.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I googled it but can't find a way to install(lib) it. Some people suggested to install 32bit version but i can't find one in synaptic. Please help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To install the 32-bit version, run:

```
apt-get install libusb-0.1-4:i386
```

This only works if MultiArch is enabled (maybe it doesn't if you upgraded from an older Ubuntu version). Look for `foreign-architecture i386` in /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch to check if MultiArch is enabled, and if it doesn't, run `echo "foreign-architecture i386" | sudo tee /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch` to enable MultiArch and `apt-get update` to get the new package lists.

Answer (score 7):

to install libusb use `sudo apt-get install libusb-0.1-4`

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. lisusb-0.1-4 is already installed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it fixed the matter for me there: http://askubuntu.com/questions/868063/installing-brscan4-for-my-brother-scanner-doesnt-work-on-a-fresh-ubuntu-16-10-i

Answer (score 6):

It failed for me even after `sudo apt-get install libusb-0.1-4:i386`/`sudo apt-get install libusb-0.1-4`.

So I did `sudo apt-get install libusb-dev` instead,
and it worked fine on my Ubuntu 64-bit system.

Comment: Had the same issue, your solution worked for me, thanks.

Comment: in fedora i get unable to find this library

Answer (score 0):

This error still exists in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS; my workaround was to install `libusb-dev`. This resolved it for me.