# Installing brscan4 for my brother scanner doesn't work on a fresh Ubuntu 16.10 install

Tags: scanner, brother, sane

I have been using the driver for my network scanner (DCP-7070DW) with success for quite a long time and I am still using it on other running computer. But I am having a hard time installing it on my fresh Ubuntu 16.10 install even if it still works after upgrading the other ones.

Running `scanimage -L` fails with a segfault.

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/scanimage 
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffcefad000)
libsane.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsane.so.1 (0x00007fd82ed31000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd82e96a000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fd82e766000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00005651dc8dc000)
```

If I run GDB

```
(gdb) run -L
Starting program: /usr/bin/scanimage -L
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff73ecd3e in __pthread_initialize_minimal_internal ()
    at nptl-init.c:322
322 nptl-init.c: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type.
```

My `/etc/sane.d/dll.conf` has got `brother4` as the last line as expected.

I have got:

- `/usr/lib64/sane/libsane-brother4.so`
- `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-brother4.so`

Any idea of how to fix the matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a `ldd /usr/lib64/sane/libsane-brother4.so` and I've got:

`libusb-0.1.so.4 => not found`

So I guessed I would need to install this dependency.

To install it, just run: `sudo apt-get install libusb-0.1-4`

And voilà:

```
$ scanimage -L
device `brother4:net1;dev0' is a Brother DCP7070DW DCP-7070DW
```

Comment: I had to do it again today :D